# Change values, data-src value to src with PHP regular expressions

Tags: php, html, regex, replace, attributes

I would like to change in all images the value of `data-src` to `src` with regular expressions and considering that it may be before or after the `src`, That is, you never know your place.

Example:

```
<img width="50" src="old.jpg" height="50" data-src="new.jpg">
```

to

```
<img width="50" src="new.jpg" height="50" data-src="new.jpg">
```

Please PHP and regular expressions!!

Thanks very much

Comment: Are these image tags the full string, or are they substrings contained in a larger string?

Comment: @quentin Incredible, duplicate? So bad I express myself? I'm asking how to do with regular expressions, I'm not asking which is the best way to do it and neither the different ways of doing this, I am asking a special case, and I assure you that many people will ask.

Comment: Several of the answers on the duplicate show how to use regular expressions on HTML.

Comment: I am not asked how to use it, then using your method, all the specific questions would be duplicated, since all the questions can be linked to how it is used, example: question about jquery, you send it to the jquey page because it explains how it's used!!! So why does stackoverflow exist?

Comment: Advice for posting: show what effort you have made in your question, demonstrate that you know Stack Overflow is not a free coding platform, and keep voting commentary to the comments rather than editing it into posts.

Comment: Quentin I'm going to unsubscribe, and I want to delete all my questions. You can continue to add negatives and put the duplicates you want, this has seemed a joke of bad taste on your part.

Comment: @jcarlosweb: you can delete your account if you wish, though that will leave the questions in place. My recommendation however is to take a break for a day or two, don't worry about getting some downvotes, and resolve to ask a better question next time. Stack Overflow does take a bit of getting used to, since tech forums have historically allowed pretty much anything to be on topic. We are focussed on building a collection of questions that will be useful for a wide audience here, and not everything will make the cut. That's OK.

Comment: (If you wish to reply to a specific person, then use their handle please, e.g. `@halfer`, `@Quentin`, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Since you want a php regex solution...

My pattern will match, regardless of attribute position, the `data-src` value and use it as the replacement value for both `src` and `data-src`.  It will unfortunately omit other attributes.  This may or may not be an issue for your project.  If it is, please update your question with a better representing sample input.

`/<img[^>]+data-src=("[^"]+")[^>]*>/`

[Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/o0PW2M/7)

Comment: Thank you @mickmackusa , we are very near, and exactly, we do not know the place of the data-src, Could be achieved by maintaining the attributes?